# ImageURI to Data URL or canvas

Tags: javascript, html, image, cordova, canvas

How can I convert Image URI to Data URL or canvas image?

I am developing a phone application in which user select image from gallery and then onclicking image User will be redirected to other application.

Currently when user selects image from gallery ImageURI is generated.

eg: Image URI = content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A40788"

connvert above imageURI to dataURL or canvas Image

Answer (score 0):

As I interpreted it, you need something like this

```
function loadCanvas(dataURL) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        // load image from data url
        var imageObj = new Image();
        imageObj.onload = function() {
          context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        };

        imageObj.src = dataURL;
      }
```

For more information look [here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-load-image-data-url/)